# Does cocoapods support MacOSX programming?

Tags: cocoapods

I am wondering if cocoapods supports MacOSX programming?

Obvious it supports ios platform, but I would like know if it supports MacOSX, I cannot find it in anywhere of its documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does.

Just include `platform :osx, '10.7'` in your podfile

`'osx'`: the platform

`'10.7'`: the minimum deployment target

More info on how to structure your podfile can be found [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)

Comment: does it defaults to ios if I does not specify platform?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the actual generation of the pods project. 
Some pods have different implementations for osx and ios. The platform identifier provides a way for cocoapods to pick to right dependency and attach it to the correct target in your project (iOS pod vs OSX pod)